# Change order of subcaption labels

Tags: graphics, captions, numbering, subcaption

I have a three part figure which, using the code below, gives this output:

[image]

However, I would like to change the labelling of the subfigures to swap (b) and (c). How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \parbox{.44\textwidth}{%
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=0.9cm]{example-image-a}}
      \vskip1em
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2.8cm]{example-image-b}}
    }
    \hskip1em
    \parbox{.55\textwidth}{%
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=6.5cm]{example-image-c}}
    }
  }
\caption{Overall caption}
\label{fig:label}  
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

With use of `tblr` defined in `tabularray`packageČ

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,varwidth}   % <===

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[c] X[c]},
        measure = vbox,
        vspan=even}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2.8cm]{example-image-a}}
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, 
                                     height=6.5cm]{example-image-b}}  \\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2.8cm]{example-image-c}}    
    \end{tblr}
\caption{Overall caption}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you this has sorted it. However, how do I prevent the subfigures from showing up in the list of figures?

Comment: @beh99, that is new question :-). I don't know, what you do, that they appears in list of figures. In new question plese provide a MWE, which reproduce your problem.